# AngularJS number input and default value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a weird issue with AngularJS and the number input. The default value will be populated for a second and then the default number disappears. Tried on FX and Chrome.

The data returned from the server is:

```
{
    "name":"Rodolfo Heller",
    "desc":"Et ullam autem iure. Facere non fuga sit. Dolorum reprehenderit voluptatem vero rem at in.",
    "sell":"44.44",
    "image":"xxxx",
    "id":"1",
    "quantity":"1"
}
```

I also have an `ng-init="product.quantity=1"` on the number input, yet the number 1 flashes then disappears.

```
<input type='number' min="1" step="1" class='form-control' ng-model="product.quantity" ng-init="product.quantity=1">
```

Any ideas why the default value disappears?

Thanks.

Comment: There are no comma in your json. Is your real server return, or is an error in a post ?

Comment: Ah sorry it is a copy and paste from the Chrome dev tools. Fixed now.

Comment: If you add {{product.quantity}} in your template. It happens the same thing ?

Comment: No, the number is visible then.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle as everything seems fine. Tested it here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10634/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

may be the issue with your datatypes return from the server,

```
{
    desc: "Et ullam autem iure. Facere non fuga sit. Dolorum reprehenderit voluptatem vero rem at in."
    id: "1"
    image: "hidden"
    name: "Rodolfo Heller"
    quantity: "1"                   // String value for quantity
    sell: "44.44"
}
```

your assign `quantity` in to a `number` input, But the the server sends the `quantity` as a `string`, if u `cast` the datatype to `int` from the server, or change `number` input to a `text` it will work.

so if you go with `int` then the data should be like,

```
{
    desc: "Et ullam autem iure. Facere non fuga sit. Dolorum reprehenderit voluptatem vero rem at in."
    id: "1"
    image: "hidden"
    name: "Rodolfo Heller"
    quantity: 1                   // int
    sell: "44.44"
}
```